# Firebase Auth SignOut() - nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase to manage users. I'm using `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword()` method to sign in the users. It works fine. But when i try to signout using the `firebase.auth().signOut()` method it gives response but the nodejs just throws the following error.

```html
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Server running on port: 3000
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:485:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (D:\web-server\TellMe-API\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (D:\web-server\TellMe-API\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (D:\web-server\TellMe-API\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at Object.next (D:\web-server\TellMe-API\api\routes\firebaseAuth.js:29:36)
    at D:\web-server\TellMe-API\node_modules\@firebase\util\dist\index.node.cjs.js:1226:22
    at D:\web-server\TellMe-API\node_modules\@firebase\util\dist\index.node.cjs.js:1336:21
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

This is the code i used to logout the user.

```js
router.post('/signout', (req, res) => {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (user) {
        firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
            res.status(200).json({
                status: 'success',
                message: 'Successfully logged/signed out'
            });
        }).catch(error => console.log('Something went wrong! ', error))
    } else {
        res.status(403).json({
            status: 'failure',
            message: 'user already logged out.'
        });
    }
});
```

I also tried using the async/await method it doesn't work too. Wherever i make a call to `firebase.auth().signOut()` method it gives the above error.

Answer (score 2):

The error

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

occurs when you try to send a response after one has already been sent.

I'm not a firebase expert but my guess is `firebase.auth().signOut()` already sends a response to the user when called.

So the code

```
res.status(200).json({
  status: 'success',
  message: 'Successfully logged/signed out'
});
```

tries to send a response after one has already been sent and generates the error.

You can simplify your code this way

```
router.post('/signout', (req, res) => {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (user) {
        firebase.auth().signOut().then(() => {
            console.log("User successfully logged out"); // Just for the example.
        }).catch(error => console.log('Something went wrong! ', error))
    } else {
        res.status(403).json({
            status: 'failure',
            message: 'user already logged out.'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But unfortunately it didn't work. Whenever i make a call to signOut() method it throws error, even when i try not to send any responses.